# Bootstrap datepicker displaying empty box

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, leaflet, pug, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to get a bootstrap datepicker to work to update layer dates in my website. However, the problem that I am getting at the moment is that when I click on the datepicker box, the calendar dropdown isn't working at all and [it just continues to display an empty box](https://drive.google.com/file/d/158jE_dQVDOqhVgzhxrgwy17nUbQLUlyY/view?usp=sharing).

I'm trying to add the datepicker inside a Leaflet textbox control and add the HTML directly into an .innerHTML method. Below is the code for the Leaflet textbox control and the datepicker itself.

```
L.Control.textbox = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function(map) {
        var info = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'datepicker');
        info.id = 'datePicker';
        //var content = getLayerTimes();
        //content = content.reverse();
        //var dropdown = prepareDropdown(content);
        //info.innerHTML = '<b>Time List</b> ' + dropdown;
        info.innerHTML += '<div class="container">';
        info.innerHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datePicker"">'
        info.innerHTML += '</div>'

        return(info);
    }
});

L.control.textbox = function(opts) { return new L.Control.textbox(opts);}
map.removeControl(map.zoomControl); 
L.control.textbox({ position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);
map.addControl(map.zoomControl); 

$('#datePicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: endDates.slice(0),
        endDate: endDates.slice(-1),
        autoclose: true,
        // enable or disable dates according to whether they are listed
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            tdate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)) + '-' + (('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2))
            if (endDates.includes(tdate)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },
    });
```

Where `endDates` is a list of dates which I will eventually pass in as the only selectable options from the datepicker. endDates is an array of format:

`['2021-05-30', '2021-05-20', '2021-05-10'....]`

In all my Googling I've found that the order in which css and js files are imported at the top of my main HTML page can have an effect, so for clarity, the scripts and css are below as well (I'm using pug as my templating engine):

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost&display=swap rel="stylesheet"')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/leaflet.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/leaflet-sidebar.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-datepicker.css')
      
script(src='/javascript/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')
script(src='/javascript/popper.min.js')
script(src='/javascript/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src="https://unpkg.com/rbush@2.0.1/rbush.min.js")
script(src="https://unpkg.com/labelgun@6.0.0/lib/labelgun.min.js")
script(src='/javascript/leaflet.js')
script(src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iso8601-js-period@0.2.1/iso8601.min.js')
script(src='/javascript/leaflet.timedimension.min.js')
script(src='/javascript/leaflet-sidebar.js')
script(async src="GOOGLE-TAG-LINK-HERE")
script(async src="GOOGLE-TAG-LINK-HERE")
script(async src="GOOGLE-TAG-LINK-HERE")
script(src='/javascript/bootstrap-datepicker.js')
```

Comment: Could be that jquery is already included in bootstrap js. Try to check that and if yes, take a version of bootstrap without jquery

Comment: I've checked the installed version - it appears to be v4.0.0, I don't think jquery is bundled with it as in the top of bootstrap.min.js is says it requires jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this seemed to be to wrap the datepicker in a `$(document).ready(function() { })` type function.

So the full datepicker function from above becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate: endDates.slice(0),
        endDate: endDates.slice(-1),
        autoclose: true,
        // enable or disable dates according to whether they are listed
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            tdate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)) + '-' + (('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2))
            if (endDates.includes(tdate)){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },
    });
});
```